# Create bash alias and function with parameter not working as expected

Tags: bash, curl

I have this script that accepts 3 parameters, and it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --header "Authorization: token $GITHUB_CLI_TOKEN" \
                        --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" \
                        --remote-name \
                        --location "https://api.github.com/repos/$1/$2/contents/$3"
```

As an example, use a valid Github access token

```
$ GITHUB_CLI_TOKEN=07D5E834792BF0B35C0DD9B1E18CC4CDB75E20E9 ./fetch.py miguelgrinberg Flask-SocketIO example/app.py
```

When I write it as an alias it does not work.

```
alias github-fetch-file='curl --header "Authorization: token $GITHUB_CLI_TOKEN" \
                         --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" \
                         --remote-name \
                         --location "https://api.github.com/repos/$1/$2/contents/$3"'
```

Neither does it work as a function

```
function github-fetch-file() {
  curl --header "Authorization: token $GITHUB_CLI_TOKEN" \
       --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" \
       --remote-name \
       --location "https://api.github.com/repos/$1/$2/contents/$3"
}
```

#### Error

```
$ github-fetch-file miguelgrinberg Flask-SocketIO example/app.py
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: miguelgrinberg
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Flask-SocketIO
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example
```

Comment: The positional parameters are expanded when you define your alias, not when you call it, reason why the alias solution does not work. Your function looks fine, it should work... if you define `GITHUB_CLI_TOKEN` before calling it. Did you do that? By the way, why do you name `fetch.py` a bash script? Are you sure you show us everything?

Comment: As per the error, try giving a filename in the `remote-name` or of you don't want the output to be saved, remove it. Also, check if the host is defined in your `hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

alias doesn't work because backslashes before end of line are literal (because of single quotes) and also there is no parameter expansion `$1` etc. are literal too, function should work as script. `GITHUB_CLI_TOKEN` can be set inline before calling function as for script.